# Is Tensorflow_Hub Universal Sentence Encoder threadsafe?

Tags: django, tensorflow, thread-safety, tensorflow-hub

I want to use Django server to implement natural language search with Universal Sentence Encoder (USE) and Annoy based database. The loading of USE is very slow:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
 import tensorflow_hub as hub
 module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"
 model = hub.load(module_url)
```

It's impossible to load pre-trained USE embedding on every browser request.

The plan is to create USE instance as a global object and store in session. Each request uses the object in session to access USE object to get embedding of query sentence.

Question:

Is Tensorflow_hub USE thread safe when getting embeddings for queries, since there is only 1 global USE object?

If running Django server in production Nginx, multiple workers will be configured. If Tensorflow is configured to use GPU, does mean only 1 worker can be configured for Nginx?

If it's not thread safe, what's good design pattern can be used here?

Answer (score 1):

I think that to solve you problem you might want to look into [TF Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) for your serving needs and it will take care of GPU, multiple workers and all the load issues.
From your Django application you could just call TF Serving API.